# Centring a div box when you cannot adjust html

Tags: wordpress, html, center

I am trying to adjust the CSS so the "product" and product information is centered and not floated to the left I cannot adjust the HTML as its given via a shortcode thats added into the WP post but maybe I could wrap it in a div?

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="products ribbon"> 
    <li class="product last first">
    <a href="http://dailybabydeals.co.nz/shop/estella-rose-designs/">
        <div class="thumbnail">
    <span class="onsale">Sale!</span>   
<img width="325" height="325" src="http://dailybabydeals.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Front-Page-325x325.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="Front Page" />         
   <div class="thumb-shadow"></div>
     <strong class="below-thumb">Estella Rose Designs</strong> 
</div>
    <span class="price"><span class="from">From: </span><del><span class="amount">&#36;25</span></del> <ins><span class="amount">&#36;19.95</span></ins></span>     
    </a>  
    <div class="buttons">
                <a href="http://dailybabydeals.co.nz/shop/estella-rose-designs/" data-product_id="2221" class="add-to-cart add_to_cart_button product_type_variable">Select options</a></div>           
</li></ul>
```

**CSS:**

[CSS](http://dailybabydeals.co.nz/wp-content/themes/maya/woocommerce/style.css?ver=3.5.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, let's try this again now that I understand your question better.  So you want to center the <ul> element as a whole?  That is a lot simpler than what I originally thought you were going for.

To do that, all you need to do is wrap the <ul> element in a span tag that is set to display as an inline-block.  Then set the containing element so that its text is centered.

Try this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style language="text/css">
      /*<![CDATA[ */
      #test1 {
        text-align: center;
      }
      #test2 {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: left;
      }
      /* ]]> */
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="test1">
      <span id="test2">
        <!-- Place your <ul> element here -->
      </span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**how it works**

- The "test2" element is set to display as an inline-block, which means it displays inline with the text.  This means that it can then be affected by properties that manipulate lines of text, such as "text-align".
- Setting "text-align" to "center" on the "test1" element makes the inline content -- the "test2" element in this case -- within it become centered on the screen.

The standard way to center a block is to set the "margin-right" and "margin-left" properties to "auto", but that only works for elements that are displayed as blocks and that have a width that is less than 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I would just put it in a div and float it next to another div with nothing in it.

http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Like in step 8 in this link.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it looks like the text "Sale!" is floated to the left is that <img> elements display as inline blocks by default, so the image is on the same line of text as the words "Sale!".  A <br /> tag immediately following the text "Sale!" would solve that problem; but you said you can't modify this HTML, right?

Given that restriction, here is how I was able to solve the problem...
Surround the HTML from your example in a <span> tag and assign it a class.  I used "test" as my class name".
Then Place this CSS in the head of the HTML document:

```
<style language="text/css">
  /*<![CDATA[ */
  .thumbnail img {
    display: block;
  }
  .test {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .test .price, .test .below-thumb  {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  /* ]]> */
</style>
```

**why it works**

- The selector for making the image display as a block solves the problem of the missing <br /> tag.
- The span tag with which you surrounded the HTML displays as an inline block.  This means that it will collapse around its contents, giving you a box within which you can center the text.
- Making the items that contain the text display as a block causes them to take a width of 100%, filling the surrounding box
- The inclusion of "text-align: center" is what finally makes the text display as centered within its container

Comment: Thanks so much but this does not work,  I have left the css up on the website for you to look at

Comment: I actually tried this code on my machine, and it appears to work.  In what way does it not work?

Comment: I think you forgot to enclose the provided HTML in a <span class="test"> element.

Comment: its wrapped in the element

Comment: I visited your link with IE9, Firefox, and Google Chrome; and the font **is** centered in all of them.  Try refreshing your browser.

Comment: I am not after the font I want to move the whole <ul class="products ribbon">  in to the middle so its not on the left